# How i can bun my tokens i tried this code but getting error

Tags: blockchain, tokens

In last there is code of burning tokens please help me i am getting this error

`TypeError: Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address) view returns (uint256)) --> Token.sol:51:17: | 51 | require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value); | ^^^^^^^^^`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address =>uint)) public allowance;
    
    uint public totalSupply =10000000000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "The Mouse";
    string public symbol = "MIK";
    uint public decimals = 18;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint_value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint_value);
    constructor(){
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint){
        return balances[owner];
        
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint_value) public returns(bool){
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >=_value, 'balaNce too low');
        balances[to] +=_value;
        balances[msg.sender] -=_value; 
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to,_value);
        return true;
        
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool){
        require(balanceOf(from) >= , 'balance tOo low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= _value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += _value;
        balances[from] -= _value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, _value);
        return true;
   
    }   

    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool){
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender , _value);
        return true;
    }
    
    
    function burn (uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        totalSupply -= __value;
        return true;
        
    }
    
    function burnFrom (address _from, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
    
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    totalSupply -= _value;

        return true;
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your contract `balanceOf()` is a function, so it must be invoked with the correct syntax, i.e. brackets -> `(` and `)`.

In your contract `balances[]` is a mapping, so each member must be accessed with the correct syntax, i.e. square brackets -> `[` and `]`.

---

The error is stating that you are trying to invoke the `balanceOf()` function using square brackets `[]`.

---

Also, this line has two underscores -> `totalSupply -= __value;`

You need to remove one of the underscores...